# Advanced usage of BayesianMaximization?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, machine-learning

There’s an example in the docs for BayesianMaximization for optimizing two suboptions of a classifier with a fixed method. I would like to optimize over multiple options for Method and their various sub-options simultaneously. But it seems there’s no way to give BayesianMaximization configurations that are interdependent, of mixed types, and/or hierarchical.

In the documentation there is an example of maximizing the log-likelihood function over a domain defined by a list of different methods for Predict:

```
trainingset = Table[n -> Sin[n], {n, 1, 15}];
testset = {3.9 -> Sin[3.9], 7.3 -> Sin[7.3]};
func[method_] := 
  PredictorMeasurements[
   Predict[trainingset, Method -> {method (* methodSubOptions here! *) }], testset, 
   "LogLikelihood"];
methods = {"LinearRegression", "NearestNeighbors", "NeuralNetwork", 
   "GaussianProcess"};
bo = BayesianMaximization[func, methods]
```

In the above, *how would I add optimization over methods and their specific sub-options together*? For example, for `Method -> "LogisticRegression"`  I would like to optimize "L1Regularization" and "L1Regularization" parameters, but for `Method -> "RandomForest"` I want to optimize "TreeNumber" and "LeafSize".

Answer (score 10):

You can pass a function that will be called to provide samples, and define it hierarchically so that it randomly chooses configurations with the desired parameters. Small example:

```
trainingset = Table[n -> Sin[n], {n, 1, 15}];

testset = {3.9 -> Sin[3.9], 7.3 -> Sin[7.3]};

ClearAll[randomForestSample];
randomForestSample[] := {"RandomForest", 
  "TreeNumber" -> RandomInteger[5], "LeafSize" -> RandomInteger[5]}
ClearAll[linearRegressionSample];
linearRegressionSample[] := {"LinearRegression", 
  "L1Regularization" -> RandomReal[1], 
  "L2Regularization" -> RandomReal[1]}
ClearAll[sampleConfiguration];
sampleConfiguration[] := 
 RandomChoice[{linearRegressionSample, randomForestSample}][]

maximizer = 
 BayesianMaximization[
  PredictorMeasurements[Predict[trainingset, Method -> #1], testset, 
    "LogLikelihood"] &, sampleConfiguration]


maximizer["EvaluationHistory"]
```

I also played around with explicitly defining a region that corresponds to the parameter space you want to optimize over, but it proved too complicated. Maybe someone with a better understanding of the system for geometric regions could explain how to do this. It might work better -- I believe the Bayesian optimizer has some notion of "nearness" which might be lost by just providing random samples.

Update:

Here is an example of sampling from a region instead. The region consists of two orthogonal spaces for the four parameters in the example.

```
linearRegion = 
 RegionProduct[Point[{{0, 0}}], Point[List /@ Range[0, 1, .2]], 
  Point[List /@ Range[0, 1, .2]]]
treeRegion = 
 RegionProduct[Point[List /@ Range[5]], Point[List /@ Range[5]], 
  Point[{0, 0}]]
combinedRegion = RegionUnion[linearRegion, treeRegion]

ClearAll[convertToLinearParams];
convertToLinearParams[config_List] := {"LinearRegression", 
  "L1Regularization" -> config[[3]], "L2Regularization" -> config[[4]]}
ClearAll[convertToTreeParams];
convertToTreeParams[config_List] :=
 {"RandomForest", 
  "TreeNumber" -> config[[1]], "LeafSize" -> config[[2]]}
ClearAll[configurationToPredictor];
configurationToPredictor[config_List] := 
 Module[{resultConfig = 
    If[config \[Element] linearRegion, convertToLinearParams[config], 
     convertToTreeParams[config]]}, 
  PredictorMeasurements[Predict[trainingset, Method -> resultConfig], 
   testset, "LogLikelihood"]]

regionMaximizer = 
 BayesianMaximization[configurationToPredictor, combinedRegion]
```

Note that the linear regression parameters, which should be continuous, are instead discrete. You can easily make it a continuous rectangle but then, because there are infinitely many points in a continuous rectangle, the probability of sampling a random forest point (with discrete params so finitely many points) drops to zero. I can't figure out a way around this.

```
linearRegion = RegionProduct[Point[{{0, 0}}], Rectangle[{0, 0}]]
treeRegion = 
 RegionProduct[Point[List /@ Range[5]], Point[List /@ Range[5]], 
  Point[{0, 0}]]
combinedRegion = RegionUnion[linearRegion, treeRegion]
(* will only ever try linear regression *)
regionMaximizer = 
 BayesianMaximization[configurationToPredictor, combinedRegion]
```

Comment: Yes I think without being able to specify regions there's much less benefit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have to agree with @M.R. The strength of the search is that it will choose the next point in some subregion. Can you adapt your code to work with intervals or rectangles etc..?

Comment: I experimented with it.

Comment: BayesianMaximization does seem to call the sampling function many times and only evaluate the main function for a few points. So it is still taking advantage of "nearness" to some extent.

Comment: I tried defining a geometric region as a `RegionProduct` of rectangles (for continuous parameters) and discrete point sets. I wasn't clever enough to come up with a good mapping from hyperparameters -> nice well-defined region that would also work with `RandomPoint`.

Comment: i added my attempts at sampling from a region. i hope you find it helpful, but i don't think you should accept my answer. i hope someone with more grasp of geometric regions comes along and gives a more complete answer.