# The hyper-parameters tuning

Tags: performance-tuning, machine-learning

I am looking for an automatic tool to hyperparameter tuning. Something similar to Random Search Cross Validation in Scikit-Learn.
Note: I used `ValidationSet` options, unfortunately, the values of hyperparameter not changed as a function of the validation set. So I look for something else

Comment: Functionality like this isn't built-in to the Wolfram Language - unfortunately, you'll have to build it yourself.

Comment: Alas and alack! I will try to import this python capability to WL.

Comment: I'd love to see it exist! Make sure you post on the community forums if you do :)

Comment: `BayesianMinimization` and `BayesianMaximization`? See the [Applications](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BayesianMinimization.html).

Comment: @AlexeyGolyshev it is good starting point

Comment: I found this answer for my question:
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/130724/advanced-usage-of-bayesianmaximization